# Click list element to slide up in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I delegate a click event to a list element that triggers it to slide up?

Here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sdh2G/

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
```

JS

```
$(document).delegate($("li"), "click", function() { $(this).slideUp(); console.log("click"); });
```

It throws the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.on()` method is quite easy to delegate events:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sdh2G/1/

```
$(document).on("click","li", function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
    console.log("click");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('li').click(function() {$(this).slideUp();});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate($("li"), "click", function()
                        ^----   Supposed to be a string and not a jQuery object
```

supposed to be

```
$(document).delegate("li", "click", function()
```

The selector argument should be of **type String** not a **jQuery object**. That is the cause of the error.

Also `delegate` is superseeded by **on** as of `version 1.7.0`

So replace that with

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
```

**[Delegate Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Sdh2G/3/)**

**[On Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Sdh2G/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(document).on( "click", "li",function() { $(this).slideUp(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sdh2G/2/